# Convert Fingerprint (hex format) into image

Tags: c++, objective-c, uiimageview, nsdata, fingerprint

Is there a code to convert this? I have hex format of fingerprint data. I want to display in `UIImageView` as image.

I tried convert hex into `NSData` and then use `imageWithData:` but it doesn't work. no image shown. obviously it's not an image. not start with FF D8 and not end FF D9.

Anybody knows these? appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want to display it as a text (human readable) or do you want to create a machine readable version of the fingerprint (e.g. qrcode)?

Comment: I just want to display as an image. I already have raw data of fingerprint (hex format). it's like having raw data (hex) of JPEG format, and display them as image.  is this possible?.

Comment: But it is _not_ an image. If you want to create an image based on the bits of the fingerprint, you should make an algorithm that draws something based on arbitrary input. It that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, searched with no result. Well, if i want to make my own, that would be impossible, any other free source/code? check : http://www.cognaxon.com/index.php?page=wsqlibrary. and i don't know, but i think my raw data in WSQ format. similiar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361115/how-to-convert-wsq-wavelet-scalar-quantization-to-jpg

Comment: http://ffpis.sourceforge.net/ seems like it may be what you want. There are also lots of good links to specifications, etc. on that page.

Comment: Where do you get the hex data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [Free FingerPrint Imaging Software (FFPIS)](http://ffpis.sourceforge.net/) is a no-cost option that can convert WSQ.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure my data is WSQ. how to check whether it is WSQ format?

Comment: you could download FFPIS, and try to use it on your data.  It appears to support a number of different formats, in addition to WSQ.

Answer (score 0):

Check this software at: http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm

It does pretty much what you want. You have to write some C++ wrappers though.